# How to use a checkbox list to validate a test?

Tags: php, html, validation, mysqli, comparison

I have a checkbox list with 10 options ik the image just have 9:

[image] and a db:

[image]

How can I compare the input in the checkbox list with the information inside the column `requerimientos` in my db?, it means values from the checkbox list must contain all of the values from `requerimientos` and it will happen with every id, just i didn't fill the other values yet, hope this clarify it

This is what I got, if it seems I have no clue what I am doing it can't be more accurate, but I dont give up. XD

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT idclasificacion,clasificacion FROM clasificacion");
        while ($rows = $query->fetch_array()) {
            echo'<div class="list-group-item"  id='. $rows['idclasificacion'] .'>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="requerimiento[]" id="" value="'.$rows['clasificacion'].'">'. $rows['clasificacion'] . '
                </label>
            </div>';
        }
    ?>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Ingresar</button>
</form>


<?php            
    //extrae los requerimiento seleccionados en forma de string, notar que requerimiento va sin []
    if (isset($_POST['requerimiento'])){                
        $requerimientos = implode ( ',', $_POST['requerimiento']);
        echo $requerimientos;
    }else {
        echo'no ha selecionado ningun requerimiento para su evento';
    }        

    echo '<br>';            

    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT requerimientos FROM tipologia");
    $rows = $query->fetch_assoc();            
    var_dump($rows);
    $requetipo=explode(',', $rows['requerimientos']);
    var_dump($requetipo);
    $validacion=in_array($requerimientos,$requetipo);
    var_dump ($validacion);                        
?>
```

Comment: What is the logic in your comparison? Do you only want to return rows from the db table if their `requerimiento` comma-separated string contains **just one of the values from the checkbox list**? or must a qualifying row contain **all of the values from the checkbox list**?  Please clarify if you can.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have a suboptimal database table design structure.  Because you have those values as comma-separated values in a single column, there are no easy ways for you query for qualifying rows.  If it is not too late, you should create a new table which separates these values (for each id in `tipologia`), then you can use JOINs to query for qualifying rows.  Otherwise, you'll need to perform some hackish comparisons like `LOCATE()` to look for qualifying rows (and this might not be reliable).  Worse of all, you could just return the entire table and use php to check -- yikes.

Answer (score 0):

tthis code compare the checked options, with the data inside requerimientos and if both are equal returns true if not false.

Now i just need to do the other options hope a for loop will help me XD

```html
<?php            
            //extrae los requerimiento seleccionados en forma de string, notar que requerimiento va sin []
            if (isset($_POST['requerimiento'])){                
                $requerimientos = implode ( ',', $_POST['requerimiento']);
                   // echo $requerimientos;
            }else {
                echo'no ha selecionado ningun requerimiento para su evento';
            }        
            
            echo '<br>';            

            $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT requerimientos FROM tipologia where tipologia='Conferencia'");
            $rows = $query->fetch_assoc();
            if($requerimientos==$rows['requerimientos']){
echo 'right';
}else{
    echo 'wrong';
}
```